# How to get specific message from other folder rather than Inbox using (WebKlex)

Tags: php, laravel

```
$oFolder = $oClient->getFolder('INBOX.Drafts');<br>
$oFolder = $oMessage = $oFolder->getMessage($uid = 2);
```

This function only return or get specific message from inbox but it not work on other folder like spam, drafts, junk, etc ,
I'm using Laravel library https://github.com/Webklex/laravel-imap#folderclass

Comment: First use the method `getFolders()` to list all folders and find the folder name, then get the message from it.

Comment: dear sir I need to open single message using uid , inbox message fetch successfully but  other folders messages not get successfully

Comment: Explain "not get successfully". It shows an error? It's empty? Show the result of `getFolders`, show something.

Comment: return empty ... if email get from other folders like INBOX.spam,INBOX.Sent,INBOX.Drafts

Comment: I want to get specific email from Folder(NBOX.spam,INBOX.Sent,INBOX.Drafts) email using uid,

Answer (score 0):

As Elias Soares mentioned above; use getFolders() to retrieve information about all the folders. Then get the complete path for a given folder name.

And then use that folder name to fetch your message.

You can use this code as example:

```
$mailBoxes = $oClient->getFolders();
$folder = $request->input("folder");

$folder = getFolderPath($mailBoxes,$folder);

$oFolder = $oClient->getFolder($folder);
```

And the code for getFolderPath():

```
function getFolderPath($mailBoxes,$folder){

        $flag=0;
        foreach($mailBoxes as $mailBox){
            if(strtolower($folder)==strtolower($mailBox->name)){
                $curFolder = $mailBox->name;
                $flag=1;
            }

            foreach ($mailBox->children as $child){
                if(strtolower($folder)==strtolower($child->name)){
                    $curFolder = $child->full_name;
                    $flag=1;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if($flag==1){
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!empty($curFolder)){
            $folder = $curFolder;
        }

        return $folder;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is why the names of folders were defined in Spanish.
In my case, I am using a Gmail SMTP server.
I found a solution and it works now for me.

```
$oClient->connect();
$oFolder = $oClient->getFolder('Enviados');
```

You can access any folder.

Drafts             -> Borradores

Highlights(stared) -> Destacados

Sent               -> Enviados

Important          -> Importantes

Trash              -> Papelera

Spam               -> Spam

Everybody          -> Todos